# JavaScript storing single values into date format

Tags: javascript, date, conditional-statements

I am working on a "rent a car" web app... so, user can choose dates "from" and "until" he wants to rent a car.. this values are stored into single variables (see below):

```
//BACK
var backDay = parseInt(jQuery('#back_day').val(),10);
var backMonth = parseInt(jQuery('#back_month').val(),10);
var backYear = parseInt(jQuery('#back_year').val(),10);
var backHours = parseInt(jQuery('#back_hour').val(),10);
var backMinutes = parseInt(jQuery('#back_minute').val(),10);
//FROM
var fromDay = parseInt(jQuery('#from_day').val(),10);
var fromMonth = parseInt(jQuery('#from_month').val(),10);
var fromYear = parseInt(jQuery('#from_year').val(),10);
var fromHours = parseInt(jQuery('#from_hour').val(),10);
var fromMinutes = parseInt(jQuery('#from_minute').val(),10);
var freeKm = parseInt(jQuery('#freeKm').val(),10);
var group = jQuery(groupKON).val();
```

So, because owner noticed that in some periods of the year demand is higher, during this period (season) he would like to increase the price for car rental.

So, between below dates price should go up.

saison1 1.3.17-21.5.17  15% price up
saison2 19.06.17-02.07.17  10% price up
saison3 12.09.17-31.10.17  10% price up

My question is how to store the date into a variable so I can write conditional statement ?

For instance:

```
    if(date == saison1) {
function increaseThePrice() {
newPrice = price*1.5;
return newPrice;
}
```

I hope my question is clear enough!

Thanks in advance!

Denis

Comment: Don't you use server? Why to store date in a variable when you can easily store dates in a database on server, get season-dates from server when you need it, and compare it with current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i belive @Softberry is right, you shouldn't put this on the client side.

i incorporated the change suggested by @RobG. (

> "…all the dates constructed in this solution are GMT+0…" only if that is the time zone of the host running the script, or if you were to use new Date(Date.UTC(2017,9-1,17)). There is no need to supply zero values, missing parameters are treated as zero by default (except for the date, it defaults to 1).

now,  if you use it on client or server, the problem remains the same.

here is a javascript solution

```
/** main logic */
function getCostForInterval(basePrice,from,back){
  var total=0;
  var seasonAdjustments=getSeasonPriceMultipliers();
  /* iterate through each day of the interval (from-back)*/
  for(
    var d=from;/* start */
    d.getTime()<=back.getTime();/* end condition */
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)/* increment by one day */
  ){
    total+=basePrice*getAdjustmentForDate(d,seasonAdjustments);
  }
   return total;
 }


/** getAdjustmentForDate returns either 1 or
   * or the corresponding price multiplier
   * when the date falls into a season
   */
function getAdjustmentForDate(date,seasons){
  var multiplier=1;
  for(var ix=0;ix<seasons.length;ix++){
    var season=seasons[i];
  /** if date falls inside current season
    **/
    if(season.begin.getTime()<date.getTime()
      && date.getTime()<season.begin.getTime() ){
      return season.multiplier;
    }
  }
  /** if date doesn't fall inside any
    * of the season intervals */
  return multiplier;
}

/*** getSeasonPriceMultipliers 
  ** returns an array of intervals where 
  ** price modifications may apply
  ** 
  ** you can change the data retrieving mechanism
  ** from hard coded to an http/ajax call
***/
function getSeasonPriceMultipliers(){
   var saisons=[
  {
    begin : new Date(Date.UTC(2017,3-1,1,0,0,0)),
    end : new Date(Date.UTC(2017,5-1,21,23,59,59)),
    multiplier : 1.15
  },
  {
    begin : new Date(Date.UTC(2017,6-1,19,0,0,0)),
    end : new Date(Date.UTC(017,7-1,2,23,59,59)),
    multiplier : 1.10
  },
  {
    begin : new Date(Date.UTC(2017,9-1,17,0,0,0)),
    end : new Date(Date.UTC(2017,10-1,31,23,59,59)),
    multiplier : 1.10
  }
 ];
  return saisons;
}
```

and test

```
 function test(BASE_PRICE,backDay,backMonth,backYear, backHours,backMinutes,
fromDay,fromMonth,fromYear,fromHours,fromMinutes
){
var from=new Date(fromYear,fromMonth,fromDay,fromHours,fromMinutes,0)
var back=new Date(backYear,backMonth,backDay,backHours,backMinutes,0)
return getCostForInterval(BASE_PRICE,from,back)
}
```

the solution does not take into account time zones, all the dates constructed in this solution are GMT+0.
be aware of the time-zone differencies between the point of retrieval and the point of return. if the price is per day the summertime shift will pose no problem, if the price is per hour, you need to adjust that accordingly.

if you use javascript on client side i recommend wrapping this whole thing in an IIFE and exposing only the function getCostForInterval, use an http call to retrieve season data in the function getSeasonPriceMultipliers and eventually uglify the whole thing( source and json )

Comment: "*…all the dates constructed in this solution are GMT+0…*" only if that is the time zone of the host running the script, or if you were to use `new Date(Date.UTC(2017,9-1,17))`. There is no need to supply zero values, missing parameters are treated as zero by default (except for the date, it defaults to 1).

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

## Setting Price related information through client side script may be dangerous

If you set discounts through JavaScript, users can simply modify it and make an order instead of 15% say 95% . So be careful. Set price and discounts with server script not with JavaScript

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort!

Answer (score -1):

Date is nothing else than a formatted string, so it can be transformed to a Date object, form custom dates, etc. That means that you can store it as a normal string, but you need to use known date format.

```
var date = "2016/02/12"; // for example
```

But well, storing the discount date in client's browser with javascript gives him full control of your javascript data, so it can be easily manipulated and misused. You should definitely use some back-end for it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort!